# Is it possible to access lock screen elements with iOS UIAutomation?

Tags: ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

There are methods lock() and unlock() in UIATarget, but they were deprecated and don't seem to work any more (calling them gives undefined function error).

There is lockForDuration() method, but it does not return until screen is unlocked.

If I set a passcode for screen unlock, then after lockForDuration() is returned (of course without being able to unlock the screen), I can dump lock screen elements with logElementTree() function. But at the same time I can't interact with them.

Is there a way to overcome these obstacles?

Comment: Why do you need to lock the screen for? Would it be enough for you to suspend the app for a while? Anyhow, you can do some reverse engineering on the up automation framework, get the headers and use the lock methods from inside your app...

Comment: @roy Lock screen in my case also has controls that affect the app. Just auto locking + unlocking is not enough. Not sure what you mean about reverse engineering. Is that makes possible lock screen access from automation scripts? And I need it to work on real devices, not in simulator.

Comment: @jesse hey, your question is a bit older already,but I am interested in how you solved your problem. I want to lock my screen and unlock it by swiping on the APNS I got in the locked screen state. I first need to manage to just lock the screen for no certain duration, will figure that somehow. How did you interact with the UI Elements on the locked screen, by doing things by coordinate? thanks for any info...Jules

Comment: @julesmummdry no, unfortunately I could not do it in any managable way.